# add value in two-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

add value to one-dimentional array in php is:

```
$arr1[] = $value;
```

how to add value to two dimentional array? I have tried this:

```
$arr2[] = $arr2[$time][$val1];
```

But it's not correct. Is there anyone can point out the error. Thanks!

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Rupesh Beat me to it. A simple Google search on the part of the asker would have presented the correct answer, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array['foo'] = array('bar');
$array['foo'][] = 'baz';
```

`print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => baz
        )

)
```

Or with numeric indices:

```
$array[] = array('bar');
$array[0][] = 'baz';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
$arr2[$time][] = $val1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$arr[][] = "Value"
```

Indicate the two dimention value at the $arr var